# jQuery: How can I check if a block in my document is inside the viewport or outside of it?

Tags: jquery, triggers, scroll, visible, viewport

I am basically trying to trigger a function if the footer is inside the viewport.

How can I check whether the footer is currently visible in the viewport?

I assume I will have to put it into the `$(window).scroll()` event so that the listener becomes true once the footer becomes visible but what the function should be I just can't figure out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading,

Jannis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the top of the footer element is greater than the window height. Something like

```
$("#yourfooterid").position().top > $(window).height()
```

Comment: Hooking this check to `onload` (is it visible initially) and `onscroll` (is it visible after scrolling) event handlers should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer more helpful when looking for something similar: [jQuery Show/Hide Div when Section is in Viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031649/jquery-show-hide-div-when-section-is-in-viewport?rq=1)

Or jump straight to Alison's example here: http://jsfiddle.net/EADDt/