# jQuery Show/Hide Div when Section is in Viewport

Tags: jquery, viewport

My code at the moment is here: http://www.jaygeorge.co.uk/gwennan-sage

You'll see two green arrows that are in a fixed position at the bottom of the page.
I'm having trouble getting jQuery to hide these divs (#timeline-buttons) when the Timeline section is NOT in view, preferably using the fade() technique.

I've tried a Viewport plugin but can't get it to work properly with if statements, I'm sure it can be done with normal jQuery by measuring div heights somehow.

Any advice appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the green arrows and then onscrolling, test to see if the timeline div position is greater than the window height plus scrolling offset.  If greater then that means that the timeline div is in view and the arrows should be shown.

Here is a quick fiddle demonstrating the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/EADDt/

Answer (score 0):

Move these arrows into `#gwennan-header` and remove the fixed css attribute and set the z-index. That way you won't need any Javascript at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the point is that the arrows should be visible when you're scrolling further down through the credits on the timeline. Plus it's much more user friendly / ergonomic if the arrows are at the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: What do the arrows do when your on the timeline? Or do they cycle through the sections? It looked like to me that it belonged on the image in the header, to scroll through a series of images left and right

Comment: Yes they scroll through the timeline, but it's not really relevant. The arrows were originally in the header image but I decided that it was quite awkward when scrolling downwards on the timeline, so the arrows should always be fixed at the bottom of the window for usability (but obviously I'd like to hide the timeline arrows when scrolling through other sections).

Comment: Well if this is for "usability" it's confused the hell of me, god knows what it does for a non-technical user. If it's to scroll through the sections (i.e. up and down the page) arrows down and up would be more appropriate. Anyhow, the viewpoint plugin should do the trick for you, maybe you could share the code you tried.

Comment: Right. I see what your trying to do now. It's still a bit confusing to the user, the arrows do different things depending on where you are on the page. That's unpredictable behvaiour, which is not good from a userability viewpoint. I'd suggest to have arrows in the header that scroll through the different page sections (or get rid of these, they are pointless anyway), then some seperate arrows that stay within the context of the sliding timeline element. No Javascript will be needed. No confused users.